# Getting error in screen-sharing development

Tags: javascript, screensharing

I'm developing a screen-sharing tool using conference.js and am getting the error message below.

What am I doing wrong?

> 192.168.1.17 - - [10/Jun/2015:16:05:10 +0530] "GET /js/conference.js HTTP/1.1" 404 506 "http://192.168.1.17/scree-share/index.html"
>   "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101
>   Firefox/31.0"

Comment: If you input manually http://192.168.1.17/js/conference.js in your navigator, does it respon with the js file or do you get a 404 ?

Comment: what did you try so far? how does your directory structure looks like